# What are the officialy supported search languages in Alfreso?

Tags: alfresco

I have heard a rumor: ""solr-alfresco" is a technical query language - it is not officially supported. Only "fts-alfresco" and "cmis-alfresco" are supported and recommended. I.e. "fts-alfresco" is the high-level language, and depending on query and system configuration, can use either "solr-alfresco" or "db-afts"."

But our complex system rely on "solr-alfresco" query language, could you tell me does it for long life or not?
The query languages in Alfresco work very different , the "fts-alfresco", "cmis-alfresco", "solr-cmis" are hit the limit 1000 max (limit could be overridden in properties) and do not allow to get more than limit even using a pagination. The "solr-alfresco" , "solr-fts-alfresco" - allow us to get all documents using the pagination

Comment: Are you using Alfresco Community or Alfresco Enterprise? (Answer may differ)

Answer (score 0):

Following are officially "full support" languages by search service:

LANGUAGE_CMIS_ALFRESCO
LANGUAGE_CMIS_STRICT
LANGUAGE_FTS_ALFRESCO
LANGUAGE_LUCENE
LANGUAGE_SOLR_ALFRESCO
LANGUAGE_SOLR_CMIS
LANGUAGE_SOLR_FTS_ALFRESCO
LANGUAGE_XPATH

https://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/references/dev-services-search.html